# How can I load content on the same page from a search

Tags: views, 7, theming, ajax, javascript

So the idea is to load the results of the search on the same page. I was told to look into SOLR, but it looks like we have something similar to SOLR , and we just need to know how to load new page content into our drupal site. Alternate to iFrame.

[image: font page]

[image: searching]

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

you to load the search results on the same page - the same page as what? do you mean without a page refresh? If that's the case, then I think you're looking for [Search API Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_ajax):

```
This module can ajaxify Seach API pages and views. Ajax made possible by
Drupal 7 core's jQuery BBQ (previous YUI3 History library is dropped).
```

and perhaps [Ajax Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_facets):

```
This module allows you to create facet filters which working by AJAX.
Filters and search results will be updated by AJAX.
```

There are a few more suggestions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3195/does-drupal-have-an-ajax-solution-for-search-results-preferably-with-apachesol)

Comment: Yeah, without a page refresh. Thank you for your answer. I was just told that none of the information the user will be searching for will be in the drupal site. Our catalog is being hosted and serviced by a 3rd party. So the question now is can we display the information from the search result on the same page with ab iframe?

Comment: so, are you trying to use the Drupal site as a front-end and then feed the search criteria to another site that will do the actual search and return the results to the Drupal site, or is the search itself as well as the results part of the other site (i.e. - is all of the search page elements contained within the frame)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, feed the search criteria to another site that will do the actual search and return the results to the Drupal site

Comment: First you will need to create a custom Form, and then doing that depends on the API for the other site. The answer depends on the type of data returned from the search API